# ARM "thumb-only" binaries

Tags: binary, arm, thumb

is there a source on the net for ARM ELF binaries that only use thumb (thumb-1, no thumb-2) instructions?

(Yes, I came to read that Linux is not capable of running on thumb-only processors.)

The content of the binaries should otherwise be as "normal" as possible, I want to use them as training data for a classifier.

Comment: you could compile some your self, find a toolchain and compile for ARM7 but I think you'd be better off looking at the ISA instead

Comment: yes, very easy to do.  http://github.com/dwelch67/thumbulator or many of my arm based repos have thumb only and thumb+thumb2 examples (As well as arm examples for the cores that support the classic instruction set).

Comment: linux not being able to run likely has to do with one or a handful of things that may be there now or could be leveraged through peripherals

Comment: mux, would you mind to tell me how I can train a classifier by looking at the ISA?